# Validation of viewstate MAC failed error - when deployed to GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have made website in asp.net, it is running perfectly in local host. But when I deploy this website in Godaddy shared Windows hosting it gives mentioned error in some of pages:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed

I have set the machine key in the web config. But still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I don't use asp.net, but I'd wager the above is not sufficient for readers to be able to determine the problem. Are there any error logs you can offer? Please note that "I have searched the web" is not sufficient to demonstrate that you actually have, and is not worth adding to questions.

Comment: Grammar, wrong error & title, there is no viewstate "mvc", it's called MAC.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840899/asp-net-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed