# viewstate MAC failed at asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a 11 website with the same code with only different data, I copy the same website in sub domain of the original website, Different data come from id for every website in dataaccess, the code always work right but sometimes 
when some pages like " register or login"   cause a error page

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster

i work with framework 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of shared webhosting. Please check below useful links

[Asp.net Validation of viewstate MAC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840899/asp-net-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed) [Stackoverflow]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors